# Return character from ASCII code in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, char, ascii

I made a program for coding text strings in Batch. Now, I have to convert the ASCII code to a character. In reality, I have to do the opposite.
I divided the chars of the strings and I want to translate it to ASCII.
I found a good command to convert ASCII to char:

```bash
cmd /c exit 65
echo %=exitcodeAscii%
```

But, when I run it in a for cycle it stops working. With the for iteration I verify if the ASCII code (the for index) is the same of the character.

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set char=A
for /L %%a in (32,1,126) do (
  cmd /c exit %%a
  echo %=exitcodeAscii%
  if %=exitcodeAscii% EQU %char% echo %%a
)
```

It seems that the command doesn't work. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set char=A
for /L %%a in (32,1,126) do (
  cmd /c exit %%a
  echo !=exitcodeAscii!
  if "!=exitcodeAscii!" EQU "%char%" echo %%a
)
```

Two little changes:
a) *using*  delayed expansion (you already *enabled* it)
b) qoutes around the `if` arguments to prevent syntax errror with empty varaibles (especially here the space for `%%a = 32`, which `if` can't handle on it's own).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the boss. Just read, fart, and applause.

```
cls
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
chcp 65001 >nul
set title_script=char to hex
title %title_script%

rem Encode this file script in UTF-8 with BOM and let the first line blank



set ansi_code_page=1252
rem 1250    Central European
rem 1251    Cyrillic
rem 1252    Western European (Latin 1)
rem 1253    Greek
rem 1254    Turkish
rem 1255    Hebrew
rem 1256    Arabic
rem 1257    Baltic
rem 1258    Vietnamese



chcp %ansi_code_page% >nul
set /p character=Character = 
set "character_ascii="
call :function_char_to_ascii character character_ascii
echo Character %character% = %character_ascii%

pause
exit

:function_char_to_hex
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set character=!%~1!
    set tmp_file=%~dpn0_tmp.txt
    echo !character!> "%tmp_file%"
    set tmp_0_file=%~dpn0_tmp_0.txt
    for %%a in ("%tmp_file%") do fsutil file createnew "%tmp_0_file%" %%~za >nul
    set "character_hex="
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('fc /B "%tmp_file%" "%tmp_0_file%"') do set "character_hex=!character_hex!%%a"
    del /f /q "%tmp_file%"
    del /f /q "%tmp_0_file%"
    if /i "%character_hex:~-4%" == "0D0A" set character_hex=%character_hex:~0,-4%
    endlocal & set %~2=%character_hex%
goto :eof

:function_change_base_number
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a input_base=%~1
    set input_number=!%~2!
    set /a output_base=%~3

    for %%i in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") do (
        call set "input_number=!input_number:%%~i!"
    )

    set map=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    set map_base=!map:~0,%input_base%!
    set /a position=0
    set input_number_check=%input_number%
    :loop_1
        set current_map_base_character=!map_base:~%position%,1!
        set input_number_check=!input_number_check:%current_map_base_character%=!
        if "!input_number_check!" == "" goto next_1
        set /a position+=1
        if "!map_base:~%position%,1!" NEQ "" goto loop_1
        echo Error. Invalid character in base %input_base%.
        echo.
        pause
        exit
    :next_1

    set /a carry_flag=1
    set "input_number_tmp=%input_number%"
    set "result_decimal="
    :loop_2
        set "input_number_tmp_digit=%input_number_tmp:~-1%"
        if %input_number_tmp_digit% LEQ 9 goto next_2
        for /l %%i in (10,1,%input_base%) do (
            if /i "%input_number_tmp_digit%" EQU "!map:~%%i,1!" (
                set "input_number_tmp_digit=%%i"
                goto :next_2
            )
        )
        echo Error.
    :next_2
    set /a result_decimal+=input_number_tmp_digit * carry_flag
    set /a carry_flag *= input_base
    set "input_number_tmp=%input_number_tmp:~0,-1%"
    if defined input_number_tmp goto :loop_2

    set /a input_number_tmp=%result_decimal%
    set "result="
    :loop_3
        set /a "division_remainder=input_number_tmp %% !output_base!"
        set /a "input_number_tmp /= !output_base!"
        set result=!map:~%division_remainder%,1!%result%
        if "%input_number_tmp%" NEQ "0" goto loop_3
    endlocal & set %~4=%result%
goto :eof

:function_char_to_ascii
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "character=!%~1!"
    set "character_hex="
    set "character_dec="
    rem Character " is forbidden
    if "%character%" == " " (
        set "character_hex=20"
        set "character_dec=32"
    )
    rem On this line, write a tabulation between the quotes, not 4 spaces.
    if "%character%" == "   " (
        set "character_hex=9"
        set "character_dec=9"
    )
    if "%character%" == ")" (
        set "character_hex=29"
        set "character_dec=41"
    )
    if "%character_hex%" == "" (
        set "character_hex="
        call :function_char_to_hex character character_hex
        set "character_dec="
        call :function_change_base_number 16 character_hex 10 character_dec
    )
    rem echo %character% = %character_dec% (x%character_hex%)
    endlocal & set %~2=%character_dec%
goto :eof
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

When I use `!=exitcodeAscii!` to do a multiple Character match, it'll execute very slowly, and I don't know why.

```
set "ascii_str= #$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
echo %time%
:ascii_multiple
if defined ascii_str (
set "char=!ascii_str:~0,1!"
for /l %%0 in (32, 1, 126) do cmd /c exit %%0 &if "!=exitcodeAscii!" EQU "!char!" echo %%0
set "ascii_str=!ascii_str:~1!"
) else (echo %time% &pause)
goto ascii_multiple
```

> start: 11:21:27.00 end: 11:22:29.25 about to 1min

However if I do a new way to convert char or string to Ascii:

```
@echo off &setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 1252 >nul

set "ascii_table=   #$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
set "ascii[33]=^!" &set "ascii[34]=""

:main
set /p "string=String:"
call :str_ascii
echo. &goto main

:str_ascii
if defined string (
set "char=!string:~0,1!"
call :char_ascii
set "string=!string:~1!"
) else (exit /b 0)
goto str_ascii

:char_ascii
set /a index=32
if "!char!"=="!ascii[33]!" echo !ascii[33]! = 33 &exit /b 0
if "!char!"=="!ascii[34]!" echo !ascii[34]! = 34 &exit /b 0
if "!char!"=="" exit /b 1
for /l %%0 in (0, 1, 94) do (
if "!char!"=="!ascii_table:~%%0,1!" echo !char! = !index! &exit /b 0
set /a index+=1)
echo cannot find char &exit /b 1
```

> In this function, I can handle Ascii char 32-126.

In this case I try to use [Lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) to improve efficiency.

And I think `!=exitcodeAscii!` was need execute too many commands, because if you want to find last char `~` you muse need to execute command for 94 times.

So I put all Ascii Characters to one string and use `!ascii_table:~%%0,1!` to get single Character in ascii table, and set /a index to count the Decimal value.

It just like set array one by one and match char each other:

```
set "ascii[32]= "
...
set "ascii[126]=~"
```

Test String:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

The speed of running all Characters is 19:33:32.19 to 19:33:32.94 - under 1 second.

If you want to use decimal value to find char you also can change few codes:

```
:main
set /p "enter=Decimal:"
if defined enter set /a dec=%enter% &call :dec_ascii
echo. &goto main

:dec_ascii
set /a index=32
if !dec!==33 echo !ascii[33]! &exit /b 0
if !dec!==34 echo !ascii[34]! &exit /b 0
if not defined dec exit /b 1
for /l %%0 in (0, 1, 94) do (
if !dec!==!index! echo !ascii_table:~%%0,1! &exit /b 0
set /a index+=1)
echo cannot find char &exit /b 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).